# How do I merge 2 table in 1 and change value from the second table to negative value before merge

Tags: sql, ms-access

Table 1 :

| TheName | TheVal1 |
| --- | --- |
| Blue | 2 |
| Red | 8 |
| Orange | 6 |
| Green | 13 |
| Blue | 14 |
| Green | 25 |

Table 2 :

| TheName | TheVal2 |
| --- | --- |
| Blue | 9 |
| Red | 30 |
| Pink | 8 |
| Green | 10 |
| Blue | 3 |
| Green | 2 |

**Output excepted :**

| TheName | TheVal |
| --- | --- |
| Blue | 4 |
| Red | -22 |
| Pink | -8 |
| Green | 26 |
| Orange | 6 |

**Calculation details :**

```
Blue = (2+14)-(9+3) = 4
Red = (8)-(30) = -22
Pink = (0)-(8) = -8
Green = (13+25)-(10+2) = 26
Orange = (6)-(0) = 6
```

**What I did try :**

So Basicly my query should do the following :

```
SELECT TheName,SUM(TheVal1) - (SELECT TheName,SUM(TheVal2) FROM Table2 GROUP BY TheName) FROM Table1 GROUP BY TheName
```

But this throw the following error :

> You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word in the main query's FROM clause. Revise the SELECT Statement of the subquery to request only one field

I think I have to merge both table in 1 and convert the new values to negatives values so this should give the following table :

| TheName | TheVal |
| --- | --- |
| Blue | 2 |
| Red | 8 |
| Orange | 6 |
| Green | 13 |
| Blue | 14 |
| Green | 25 |
| Blue | -9 |
| Red | -30 |
| Pink | -8 |
| Green | -10 |
| Blue | -3 |
| Green | -2 |

And then just execute the following SQL code :

```
SELECT TheName,SUM(TheVal) FROM NewMergedTable GROUP BY TheName
```

Can someone help me with this ?

**Please note that I am working on ACCESS**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a select from suquery with union

```
select TheName, sum(TheVal) 
from (

    select TheName, sum(TheVal1) TheVal
    from table1 
    group by TheName 
    UNION 
    select TheName, -1*sum(TheVal2)
    from table2 
    group by TheName 

)    t group by TheName
```

Comment: answer  updated for the new column name